# Android Jquery Listview Filter ruins the layout

Tags: android, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, filter

I try do a simple listview with filter in Android 4.1.2 and it looks ruin the fixed layout like the fixed position for header/footer and the listview become not fit in the screen anymore soon as you tap into the filter box.

Is it a bug or something wrong with my code. Following is the simple code:

```
<ul id="mylist" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="b" data-filter="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
    <li data-role="list-divider">B</li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>
    <li data-role="list-divider">C</li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Caleb Booth</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Christopher Adams</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Culver James</a></li>
</ul>
```

Screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/3xs0dqu7v/

Answer (score 0):

Try with the correct html markup. DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/AeXnV/8/

I think you forgot `<div data-role="content">`?

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="mylist" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="b" data-filter="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">B</li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">C</li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Caleb Booth</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Christopher Adams</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Culver James</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I found the problem. It is caused by class="ui-bar" in the footer. If I remove this class="ui-bar", it fixes the right side layout issue, but the header and the footer become not fix in position anymore. Here I paste the code for you to reproduce the problem. The problem is in PhoneGap, I don't know if other browser has the issue or not.

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <ul id="mylist" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="b" data-filter="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">B</li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">C</li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Caleb Booth</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Christopher Adams</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Culver James</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="emailCode" data-role="button"
            data-icon="star">Email</a>
</div>
```